# Node REST API using Flatiron?

Tags: node.js, flatiron.js

Is there a difference between faltiron's [restful](https://github.com/flatiron/restful) and [node-restify](https://github.com/mcavage/node-restify/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

restful takes resources created with [resourceful](https://github.com/flatiron/resourceful) and automatically generates RESTful routes for them (similar to the way Rails does).

node-restify is a library for generating your own RESTful APIs; it does no auto-generation of routes for you.

Comment: Thanks :) So are there any pros/cons of using restful instead of node-restify?

Comment: Well, they do different things. If you're already using resourceful and you want RESTful routes for them, restful might be a good project to go with; but if you're not using resourceful, it's out of the picture. node-restify is similar to Express; the author [explains why you might want to use it on the project's site](http://mcavage.github.com/node-restify/).